# Adding crlf character in xml file

Tags: xml

I am trying to FTP a text file which is generated on unix server to Mainframe dataset. The file is generated as text file by extracting data in queue. The configuration is done via XML file like below:

```
</config> <exporters> <exporter id="REPORTING"> <number-of-exporter>1</number-of-exporter> <output-directory-name>/EXPORTER/OUT/</output-directory-name> <output-file-pattern>export_%.txt</output-file-pattern> <jndi-source-queue-name>queue.name</jndi-source-queue-name> <jndi-source-connection-factory>queue.name</jndi-source-connection-factory> <export-sleep-time>500</export-sleep-time>
```

Could you please let me know how can I add CRLF character in above code.

Comment: Sorry the code is wrongly posted. I will add the exact code shortly

Comment: Add a CRLF where? For XML, `xmllint --format` can help reformat XML.

Comment: What is the CRLF character? Is that a special unicode code point combining the CR character and LF character?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an LF after every closing tag, you could use `sed`:

```
sed -e 's:</[^>]*>:&\n:g' inputfile.xml
```

Use `\r` or `\r\n` if you really want a CR or CRLF instead of just an LF (aka "newline").

Optionally use `sed`'s `-i` or `--in-place` option to cause the actual input file(s) to be changed, rather than just output to stdout.

```
sed -i -e 's:</[^>]*>:&\n:g' inputfile.xml
```

NOTE: `-i` is not available on archaic versions of `sed` that nobody sane uses these days.  Use a tmp file instead.

Answer (score 0):

`unix2dos <file>` the file

char method is very tricky when it comes to read config in both, UX (LF) or Windows (CRLF), even on Mac (CR)

[`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) to convert CRLF > LF

[`unix2dos`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos) to convert LF > CRLF

Notepad++ allows your to search and replace those

- `\n` = LF
- `\r` = CR
- `\r\n` = CRLF

Comment: this is not isolated to XML, any text file can be changed the return method to fit the target system ;)

Comment: the funny thing is that all this stuff comes from the typewritters, since LF was one line down move on the sheet, and CR was both, sheet goes right to left and one line down.